# Removing new line character from pipes delimited file for lines not starting with timestamp

Tags: regex, sed, notepad++, data-cleaning

Here is an example of the data:

```
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|147374 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|KRISTCOS 11:13 AM 6/22/2013
NUM: 90834098
data: 0394884
cX: 90h010f03040f
mR: 034050t0ds0
cNUM: 034050t0ds0
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|0950704421406        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|MRS
2013-06-22 00:00:50.379487|0441813679603        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|TN 90210
```

I am in need of a script to remove the new line character from lines that do not begin with a timestamp.  In the example above, lines 2-5 would be appended to the last field in the first line in a sort of text blob.  I know how to detect the good lines,

```
grep '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*' testfile
```

and also the bad lines,

```
grep '^[^0-9][^0-9][^0-9][^0-9].*' testfile
```

The question now is, how do I apply this (using sed?) in order to put the lines following a 'good' line back into the last field of this line.  Any help here would be much appreciated.

Here is an example of the desired output:

```
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|147374 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|KRISTCOS 11:13 AM 6/22/2013 NUM: 90834098 data: 0394884 cX: 90h010f03040f mR: 034050t0ds0 cNUM: 034050t0ds0
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|0950704421406 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|MRS
2013-06-22 00:00:50.379487|0441813679603 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|TN 90210
```

Edit:

There is some disagreement as to which is the most appropriate tool.  At the moment I am leaning towards notepad++.  This is close to the kind of thing I want to do but it is not quite working, maybe someone out there can help me tune it to my use case:

```
(?! [0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*

(?! [0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})  - searches for a line not like a timestamp
.*                                  - followed by anything else
```

The problem is that the .* catches the timestamp that I am attempting to negate.  Any thoughts?

Edit 2:
Thanks everyone for the helpful advice, it's definitely moving me in the right direction!  The following regex finds the problematic \n char in notepad++, but when I try to perform the substitution nothing happens:

```
Find: (.*)(\n)(?![0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})
Replace: \1
```

Does anyone have any ideas here as to how to force notepad++ to remove the problematic \n?

Edit 3:
Here is additional sample data that does not seem to work with the proposed solutions:

```
2013-06-22 00:00:02.540298|0238704723874        |SMELL TEST|HAKEKJ  |REAS|No cooking|tcna / ncc
2013-06-22 00:00:04.302887|3289749873342        |SMELL TEST|ICNIDF  |REAS|No cooking|JINUJ/CVGIND/NASR
6:13 AM 6/22/2013
VERIFIED CURLING
TN :- 834974978398
XX and YY updated
THIS IS A SENTENCE
2013-06-22 00:00:06.937545|30874987392838        |SMELL TEST|KCIDKD  |REAS|No cooking|SrutiD/cvgind/nasr
tn 4887839847
```

Comment: i think `sed` is not an appropriate tool to do this.

Comment: I should be more specific and say that I am stuck figuring out the regex to remove the newline character from a given line (if that is in fact possible).  What other tools might make this problem more tractable?

Comment: @AvinashRaj `sed` can do the job, but I agree that syntax may not be for the faint hearted. `:)`

Comment: sed is a never a good choice for a problem that involves operations across multiple input lines. Use awk instead for clarity, robustness, maintainability, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
echo $(cat file) | sed -re 's/(2013-06)/@@@\1/g' | sed -re 's/@@@/\n/g'
```

This works because echo without quotes put everything in the same line, then we insert @@@ before the timestamp and the replace @@@ with new line character.

```
tiago@dell:~$ echo $(cat file) | sed -re 's/(2013-06)/@@@\1/g' | sed -re 's/@@@/\n/g'

2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|147374 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|KRISTCOS 11:13 AM 6/22/2013 NUM: 90834098 data: 0394884 cX: 90h010f03040f mR: 034050t0ds0 cNUM: 034050t0ds0 
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|0950704421406 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|MRS 
2013-06-22 00:00:50.379487|0441813679603 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|TN 90210 
2013-06-22 00:00:02.540298|0238704723874 |SMELL TEST|HAKEKJ |REAS|No cooking|tcna / ncc 
2013-06-22 00:00:04.302887|3289749873342 |SMELL TEST|ICNIDF |REAS|No cooking|JINUJ/CVGIND/NASR 6:13 AM 6/22/2013 VERIFIED CURLING TN :- 834974978398 XX and YY updated THIS IS A SENTENCE 
2013-06-22 00:00:06.937545|30874987392838 |SMELL TEST|KCIDKD |REAS|No cooking|SrutiD/cvgind/nasr tn 4887839847
```

```
tiago@dell:~$ cat file
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|147374 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|KRISTCOS 11:13 AM 6/22/2013
NUM: 90834098
data: 0394884
cX: 90h010f03040f
mR: 034050t0ds0
cNUM: 034050t0ds0
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|0950704421406        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|MRS
2013-06-22 00:00:50.379487|0441813679603        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|TN 90210
2013-06-22 00:00:02.540298|0238704723874        |SMELL TEST|HAKEKJ  |REAS|No cooking|tcna / ncc
2013-06-22 00:00:04.302887|3289749873342        |SMELL TEST|ICNIDF  |REAS|No cooking|JINUJ/CVGIND/NASR
6:13 AM 6/22/2013
VERIFIED CURLING
TN :- 834974978398
XX and YY updated
THIS IS A SENTENCE
2013-06-22 00:00:06.937545|30874987392838        |SMELL TEST|KCIDKD  |REAS|No cooking|SrutiD/cvgind/nasr
tn 4887839847
```

Comment: This was the command that finally did it for me: `echo $(cat testfile) | sed -re 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2})/@@@@@\1/g' | sed -re 's/@@@@@/\n/g' > result2`.  Thanks!

Comment: Good one. I don't understand though the need of `echo $(cat file) | sed '...'`, shouldn't it suffice with `sed '...' file`?

Comment: @fedorqui it's needed because there are data in different lines. when you use echo without quotes it put the whole string in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Using all of your posted sample input concatenated in one file:

```
$ cat file
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|147374 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|KRISTCOS 11:13 AM 6/22/2013
NUM: 90834098
data: 0394884
cX: 90h010f03040f
mR: 034050t0ds0
cNUM: 034050t0ds0
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|0950704421406        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|MRS
2013-06-22 00:00:50.379487|0441813679603        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|TN 90210
2013-06-22 00:00:02.540298|0238704723874        |SMELL TEST|HAKEKJ  |REAS|No cooking|tcna / ncc
2013-06-22 00:00:04.302887|3289749873342        |SMELL TEST|ICNIDF  |REAS|No cooking|JINUJ/CVGIND/NASR
6:13 AM 6/22/2013
VERIFIED CURLING
TN :- 834974978398
XX and YY updated
THIS IS A SENTENCE
2013-06-22 00:00:06.937545|30874987392838        |SMELL TEST|KCIDKD  |REAS|No cooking|SrutiD/cvgind/nasr
tn 4887839847
```

.

```
$ awk 'NR>1{pre = (/^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}/ ? ORS : OFS)} {printf "%s%s",pre,$0} END{print ""}' file
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|147374 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|KRISTCOS 11:13 AM 6/22/2013 NUM: 90834098 data: 0394884 cX: 90h010f03040f mR: 034050t0ds0 cNUM: 034050t0ds0
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|0950704421406        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|MRS
2013-06-22 00:00:50.379487|0441813679603        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|TN 90210
2013-06-22 00:00:02.540298|0238704723874        |SMELL TEST|HAKEKJ  |REAS|No cooking|tcna / ncc
2013-06-22 00:00:04.302887|3289749873342        |SMELL TEST|ICNIDF  |REAS|No cooking|JINUJ/CVGIND/NASR 6:13 AM 6/22/2013 VERIFIED CURLING TN :- 834974978398 XX and YY updated THIS IS A SENTENCE
2013-06-22 00:00:06.937545|30874987392838        |SMELL TEST|KCIDKD  |REAS|No cooking|SrutiD/cvgind/nasr tn 4887839847
```

If that's not your expected output, please update your question to show what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you like to do, since you have not provided with output example.
But if you like to connect lines, you can try this `awk`

```
awk '{printf (!/2013/?" ":RS)"%s",$0} END {print ""}'

2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|147374 |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|KRISTCOS 11:13 AM 6/22/2013 NUM: 90834098 data: 0394884 cX: 90h010f03040f mR: 034050t0ds0 cNUM: 034050t0ds0
2013-06-22 00:00:49.307121|0950704421406        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|MRS
2013-06-22 00:00:50.379487|0441813679603        |PHONE HOME|SDRKRKS|REAS|something|TN 90210
```

Comment: Good effort but it doesn't seem to work on my system.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sledge And your system is?  Did you try with data in this post or other?

Comment: It's a SUSE linux box. I tried with data that shares similar structure to this data shown above. I can't share the actual data.

Comment: If this doesn't work with your real data then update your question to show data that better represents your real data as we won't be able to guess the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -nr ':a;N;/\n[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{P;$!D;s/.*\n//p};s/\n/ /g;$!ba;p' file
```

#### Explanation:

- Create a label `:a`
- Append next line to current line on pattern space using `N`
- `/\n[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{P;$!D;s/.*\n//p}`  Test if the line that is appended starts with date if so print up to the first newline and if it is not the last line, delete up to first new line. If it is the last line delete up to the newline and print it.
- `s/\n/ /g;` for all other lines keep removing new lines.
- `ba` branch back to our label and repeat

Comment: Also close but I am thinking a negative lookaround is the way to go now.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sledge Thanks have updated the solution. Hope that works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/^[^|]*$/Ms/\n/ /;ta' file
```

If the last line appended does not contain a `|` replace the newline with a space and repeat.